# TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable -- all values are float but still I am getting the error. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, function, iteration

I am getting error -

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable-- pointed at the - for loop at -theta in Angles line.
My code is like this -

````
def anisotropy(A,Angles):
    Res_Flds=[]
    for theta in Angles:
        Res_Fld=A*math.cos(2*theta)
        Res_Flds.append(Res_Fld)
    return Res_Flds

Exp_Angles=[ 15.  30.  45.  60. 120. 135. 150. 165. 210. 225. 240. 300. 315. 330.
 345.]
Ex_Res_Flds=[-386.1 -357.7 -330.1 -308.4 -342.7 -366.9 -394.8 -425.6 -367.1 -334.
 -313.4 -340.3 -369.8 -398.5 -419.6]
p0=[50]
popt,pcov=opt.curve_fit(anisotropy,Exp_Angles,Ex_Res_Flds,p0,maxfev=1000)```
````

Comment: Exp_Angles and Ex_Res_Flds lists are not actually lists. A list has commas separating the values (I assume you want a list of floats?), ie: `exp_angles = [15.0, 30.0, 45.0, 60.0,120.0,135.0,150.0,165.0,210.0,225.0,240.0,300.0,315.0,330.0, 345.0]`

Comment: The `curve_fit` function doesn't pass the angles to your `anisotropy`, only the first parameter, one angle at a time. all the other arguments are the input parameters for the fit (to be determined by the curve_fit function). You can't do this in this way.

Comment: The error is given here.. please, check 

<ipython-input-57-243bdba9a5e9> in anisotropy(A, Angles)
     27 def anisotropy(A,Angles):
     28     Res_Flds=[]
---> 29     for theta in Angles:
     30         Res_Fld=A*math.cos(2*theta)
     31         Res_Flds.append(Res_Fld)

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

Comment: @Stevo The nparrays are passing well as argument in the Anisotropy function. The error is coming when I am trying to fit.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Can you elaborate little more !! Please.

Comment: @BipulKrMahato you need a list in your for loop. When you say for theta in Angles, it is looking for what makes up "Angles". If it is not a list it will throw that error and say that it is not iterable.

Comment: If you're creating an array "manually" in code, you have to put in commas (numpy just prints it without comas). As for `curve_fit`: it takes in x-values (your `Exp_Angles` array), y-values (your `Ex_Res_Flds`), and a function which contains a formula that calculates y(x, p0, p1, p2...), etc, where p0, p1, p2... are the parameters for the fit. So your `anisotropy(A,Angles)` is actually `anisotropy(x, p0)`. What happens is, `curve_fit` will pass all the x values, one at a time to `anisotropy`, as well as p0, which you set to be initially 50 (so `Angles` is just the number 50) -- continues -- 1/2

Comment: and it will expect it to return a result (the y as calculated by that function), so that it can compare it to the corresponding y-value in the Ex_Res_Flds array. It will then vary the parameter p0 (and others, if there are more) until it finds a combination that produces the least discrepancy - a best fit. So your `anisotropy` function cannot return an array, it must return a single value. 2/2

Comment: P.S. So, basically, if your `A` is the parameter that can vary, I think you need to do `anisotropy(theta, A)`, get rid of the loop, and just do a `return A*math.cos(2*theta)`